# custom object lookup relationship soql query to get sobject

Tags: soql

I have 2 custom object.

```
1 - namespace__object1__c
2 - namespace__object2__c
```

I have lookup relationship in custom object namespace__object2__c.

Now i want to query id record from object2 where object1 id = (provided parameter)

```
String s = 'a6T3k0000LMJcEAO';
string query = 'select ID, (select ID from namespace__object1__c where ID = :s  ) from namespace__object2__c';

SObject rObject = database.query(query);
system.debug(rObject);
```

Added:- defined relation

```
object1 namespace__object1__c   Lookup(object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a parent-child query here, since what you want is actually the child object. You should simply filter on the relationship field on `namespace__object2__c`. You also do not need, and should not use, Dynamic SOQL here; "regular" SOQL works fine:

```
Id s = 'a6T3k0000LMJcEAO';
List<namespace__object2__c> objs = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM namespace__object2__c
    WHERE namespace__object1_id__c = :s
];
```

Note that `s` should be typed as an Id, not a String. `namespace__object1_id__c` should be the API name of the relationship field from Object 2 to Object 1.

Comment: getting error --  WHERE namespace__object1_id__c = :s ^ ERROR at Row:4:Column:11 No such column 'namespace__object1_id__c' on entity 'namespace__object2__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Yes, as I stated above, you need to use the API name of the actual relationship field.